# SQL: query to show how many users have each property (grouped)

Tags: sql, jsp, ms-access, jdbc, group-by

I'm new to SQL and can't seem to ask the right question, as in every time I formulate it differently I end up with the same results: A query that groups data by several properties (users that share more than one property).

I'm writing a JSP-based website on the Glassfish server, and manage the database from MS Access.

What I'm interested in, is basically grouping by several distinct properties. Say I have a table that shows which items a user has. Something like this:

```
id  |  name |  item1  | item2  | item3  | item4  |
--------------------------------------------------
1   | name1 |   yes   |  yes   |        | yes    |
----+-------+---------+--------+--------+--------+
2   | name2 |   yes   |        |        | yes    |
----+-------+---------+--------+--------+--------+
3   | name3 |         |  yes   |        | yes    |
----+-------+---------+--------+--------+--------+
4   | name4 |   yes   |  yes   |        | yes    |
----+-------+---------+--------+--------+--------+
5   | name5 |         |        |  yes   | yes    | 
.
.
.
```

The query that I need, would return the following:

```
ItemID  |  Number of users with this item
-----------------------------------------
item1   |  3
item2   |  3
item3   |  1
item4   |  5
```

I don't see how `GROUP BY` can be used here, as the result I'm looking for basically demands that the **properties** of the original table, will now appear as the **values** in each row of the resulting table.

What is the right query, and how such operation is called (it's not *grouping* by each property, it's something else...)?

Comment: You should change your database design. Have one table for the user (user_id, name),  one for items (item_id, name) and one for user_items (user_id, item_id). With such normalized table structure queries will be easier to write.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how you could do this in Access if you need it to work on any table, but if you know the table structure you can design a query like:

```
select 'item1' as ItemID, count(*) as [Number of users with this item]
from myTable
where item1 = 'Yes'
union
select 'item2', count(*)
from myTable
where item2 = 'Yes'
union
....
```

and so on.

Comment: ... but I agree with other posters that better DB design would make this a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an aggregate query that returns 1 record with the count under each Item field. Assuming these are Yes/No type fields:

```
SELECT Sum(IIf([Item1],1,0)) AS Count1, Sum(IIf([Item2],1,0)) AS Count2, Sum(IIf([Item3],1,0)) AS Count3, Sum(IIf([Item4],1,0)) AS Count4 FROM Table1;
```

Your data structure is not normalized. Instead of 4 Item fields should be one Item field with the item code. Normalized structure would allow option for GROUP BY or CROSSTAB queries.

```
id  |  name |  item   |
----------------------+
1   | name1 |   1     |
----+-------+---------+
2   | name1 |   2     |
----+-------+---------+
3   | name1 |   4     |
----+-------+---------+
4   | name2 |   1     |
----+-------+---------+
5   | name2 |   4     |
```

Can emulate the normalized structure with a UNION query. There is no designer for UNION, must type into SQLView of query builder.

```
SELECT ID AS SourceRecID, [Name] AS User, 1 AS Item, "Item1" AS Source FROM tablename
UNION SELECT ID, [Name], 2, "Item2" FROM tablename
...;
```

Now use that query in another query to do the aggregate GROUP BY calcs. Or use it as the source for a report. A report will allow display of raw detail data as well as summary calcs.