# UNPIVOT issue between two similar queries

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

Trying to work out the question ([SQL: query to show how many users have each property (grouped)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686023/sql-query-to-show-how-many-users-have-each-property-grouped)) in oracle 12c.

```
with data (id, name, a, b, c, d) as
(
  select 1, 'name1', 'yes', 'yes', '', 'yes' from dual union all
  select 2, 'name2', 'yes', '', '', 'yes' from dual union all
  select 3, 'name3', '', 'yes', '', 'yes' from dual union all
  select 4, 'name4', 'yes', 'yes', '', 'yes' from dual union all
  select 5, 'name5',  '', '', 'yes', 'yes' from dual 
)
,
coll (a,b,c,d) as
(
  select count(a) a, count(b) b, count(c) c, count(d) d from data
)
select * from coll
unpivot 
(
  val for (col) in (a, b, c, d)
);
```

works fine and produces the desired result.

Whereas

```
with data (id, name, a, b, c, d) as
(
select 1, 'name1', 'yes', 'yes', '', 'yes' from dual union all
select 2, 'name2', 'yes', '', '', 'yes' from dual union all
select 3, 'name3', '', 'yes', '', 'yes' from dual union all
select 4, 'name4', 'yes', 'yes', '', 'yes' from dual union all
select 5, 'name5',  '', '', 'yes', 'yes' from dual 
)
--,
--coll (a,b,c,d) as
--(
select count(a) a, count(b) b, count(c) c, count(d) d from data -- Line 1685
--)
--select * from coll
unpivot 
(
val for (col) in (a, b, c, d)
);
```

produces the below error.

> ORA-00904: "D": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 1,685 Column: 50

Can someone please help to find why it is so?

Comment: how should the output look like? also how many columns a,b,c,d do you have? is it fixed?

Comment: Both posted examples produce same error with this [online fiddle](http://rextester.com/QCJTY15894):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The queries in question are different.

1) In the first query, you are counting  the number of non-`null`'s in respective columns initially and `unpivot`ing them.

2) In the second, you are `unpivot`ing first, and trying to count them. After you `unpivot` there are no columns a,b,c,d. They will be under `col`..as you are saying `val for col in (a,b,c,d)`. To get the same result as the first, use

```
select col,count(*) as val 
from data -- Line 1685
unpivot (
         val for col in (a,b,c,d)
        )
group by col
```

Comment: `In the second, you are unpivoting first, and trying to count them.` That helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
with data (id, name, a, b, c, d) as (
  select 1, 'name1', 'yes', 'yes', '',    'yes' from dual union all
  select 2, 'name2', 'yes', '',    '',    'yes' from dual union all
  select 3, 'name3', '',    'yes', '',    'yes' from dual union all
  select 4, 'name4', 'yes', 'yes', '',    'yes' from dual union all
  select 5, 'name5',  '',   '',    'yes', 'yes' from dual 
)
select * from data
unpivot (  val for (col) in (a, b, c, d) );
```

**Outputs**:

```
    ID NAME  COL VAL
------ ----- --- ---
     1 name1 A   yes
     1 name1 B   yes
     1 name1 D   yes
     2 name2 A   yes
     2 name2 D   yes
     3 name3 B   yes
     3 name3 D   yes
     4 name4 A   yes
     4 name4 B   yes
     4 name4 D   yes
     5 name5 C   yes
     5 name5 D   yes
```

There is no column `A`, `B`, `C` or `D` in the output to count.

If you want to get the same output you will need to group by `COL`:

```
with data (id, name, a, b, c, d) as (
  select 1, 'name1', 'yes', 'yes', '',    'yes' from dual union all
  select 2, 'name2', 'yes', '',    '',    'yes' from dual union all
  select 3, 'name3', '',    'yes', '',    'yes' from dual union all
  select 4, 'name4', 'yes', 'yes', '',    'yes' from dual union all
  select 5, 'name5',  '',   '',    'yes', 'yes' from dual 
)
select COL, COUNT(*) AS VAL from data
unpivot (  val for (col) in (a, b, c, d) )
GROUP BY col
ORDER BY col;
```

**Output**:

```
COL        VAL
--- ----------
A            3
B            3
C            1
D            5
```

Comment: @MTO thanks for breaking it down to explain why my second query was failing.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, given the SELECT clause you wrote, if the second query were to work at all, the result would be all in one row, in four columns labeled A, B, C, D. If **that** is what you want, then you need conditional COUNT:

```
with data (id, name, a, b, c, d) as
(
select 1, 'name1', 'yes', 'yes', ''   , 'yes' from dual union all
select 2, 'name2', 'yes', ''   , ''   , 'yes' from dual union all
select 3, 'name3', ''   , 'yes', ''   , 'yes' from dual union all
select 4, 'name4', 'yes', 'yes', ''   , 'yes' from dual union all
select 5, 'name5',  ''  , ''   , 'yes', 'yes' from dual 
)
select count(case col when 'A' then 1 end) as a,
       count(case col when 'B' then 1 end) as b,
       count(case col when 'C' then 1 end) as c,
       count(case col when 'D' then 1 end) as d
from data
unpivot 
(
val for (col) in (a, b, c, d)
);

A  B  C  D
-  -  -  -
3  3  1  5
```

Note that the values to check are 'A', 'B', 'C' and 'D', not the lower-case versions. In the UNPIVOT clause, if you don't use aliases in the IN sub-clause, the values in the COL column will simply be the names of the columns in the IN sub-clause (a, b, c, d), always in upper-case (the same as Oracle does with all column names that are not enclosed in double-quotes).

Comment: `values to check are 'A', 'B', 'C' and 'D', not the lower-case versions`. Thanks for the finer details.